# how to format amounts in indian format in google chart

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization, data-visualization, number-formatting, column-chart

My Graph is like this:

[image]

I want to show amounts like indian format 
instead of Million/Billion i want to show Thousand/Lakhs/Crores
and also in tooltip as **"27,98,99,811.34"**

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[To load a chart formatted for a specific locale](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#loadwithlocale), use the language parameter:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {//},
  language: 'hi_IN',
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Month', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'Amount', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 'April'}, {v: 279899811.34}]},
        {c:[{v: 'May'}, {v: 205855811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'June'}, {v: 10009811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'July'}, {v: 79979811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'August'}, {v: 175789911}]},
        {c:[{v: 'September'}, {v: 99899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'October'}, {v: 149899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'November'}, {v: 80899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'December'}, {v: 60899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'January'}, {v: 225899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'February'}, {v: 148899811}]},
        {c:[{v: 'March'}, {v: 150899811}]}
      ]
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      vAxis: {
        format: 'short'
      },
      legend: 'none'
    });
  },
  language: 'hi_IN',
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: it shows in **hindi (क)**, i want to show like **Thousand(K)/ Lakhs(L)/ Crores(C)**

Comment: I tried with all indian Code but not able to get desired format.. anyways thanks  **WhiteHat**

Comment: have tried using a [NumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat)?

Comment: Is there option in google chart to show L(Lakhs) instead of K for amount?